# While and if loop in Main() wanting me to remove code below it?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

When creating the While and IF loops in the code below it creates an error saying: `Unreachable code` and suggesting that I remove the below code. I do not understand the issue here and I have tried moving the while statement with the code below the rest of the code inside the Main() method, but then my JFrame just appears white. Any help?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.omg.CORBA.PRIVATE_MEMBER;


public class Game 
{
    boolean p1;

    private int counterY1 = 515, counterY2 = 515, counterY3 = 515, counterY4 = 515;
    boolean playerTurn = true;
    boolean playerTurn2 = false;
    boolean moveLoop = true;

    public void moveC1Up()
    {
        counterY1 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }
    public void moveC2Up()
    {
        counterY2 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }
    public void moveC3Up()
    {
        counterY3 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }
    public void moveC4Up()
    {
        counterY4 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public int diceRoll()
    {
        int randGen = (int)(Math.random()*1) + 1;
        System.out.print(randGen);
        return randGen; 
    }

    private JButton moveC1But, moveC2But, rollDiceButton;
    private JLabel amountRolledLabel;

    public Game()
    {


        JFrame window = new JFrame ("Main Game");
        final JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1))
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {   
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                super.paintComponent(g2d);

                int width = getWidth() / 3;
                int height = getHeight() / 11;

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight());
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height);
                }

                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);

                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
            }
        };

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel rightSidePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,1));
        moveC1But = new JButton("Move Counter 1");
        moveC2But = new JButton("Move Counter 2");
        rollDiceButton = new JButton("Roll Dice");
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC1But, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC2But, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        rightSidePanel.add(rollDiceButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.add(rightSidePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        window.setSize(700, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

        while(moveLoop  == true)
        {
            moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {

                    diceRoll();
                    moveC1Up();
                    firstPanel.repaint();
                    System.out.print(diceRoll());
                    System.out.print("Test1");
                    playerTurn = false;
                    playerTurn2 = true;
                    moveLoop = false;

                }
            });

            moveC2But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {

                    diceRoll();
                    moveC3Up();
                    firstPanel.repaint();
                    System.out.print(diceRoll());
                    System.out.print("Test1");
                    playerTurn = false;
                    playerTurn2 = true;
                    moveLoop = false;

                }
            });
        }

    }   

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Also `break;` isn't working

Comment: Rather than comment on your question, please edit the original question. Also note that there is no such thing as an `IF loop` and you should include line numbers when referring to parts of your code.

Answer (score 2):

`while(true)` will continue forever as you have no `break` statements anywhere to leave the loop. That then means that all code below the loop can never be executed.

Comment: I have edited it, please view the code above. However, it just displays a white JFrame.

Comment: That is a separate issue, please create a new question for it instead of drastically rewriting this one multiple times for all future problems.

Comment: Sure thing, I shall do that now, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no `break` statement to break the infinite loop.

That's why compile shows you error `Unreachable code` because code below `while(true)` is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code the loop doesn't let the JFrame to call `repaint();` because it is never broken until the user clicks a button, which is impossible if the JFrame didn't yet draw the components.

Here's how you should do your inputs instead.

```
package beaudoin.apps;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import sun.awt.RepaintArea;

public class Game {

    boolean p1;

    private int counterY1 = 515, counterY2 = 515, counterY3 = 515, counterY4 = 515;
    boolean playerTurn = true;
    boolean playerTurn2 = false;

    public void moveC1Up() {
        counterY1 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public void moveC2Up() {
        counterY2 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public void moveC3Up() {
        counterY3 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public void moveC4Up() {
        counterY4 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public int diceRoll() {
        int randGen = (int) (Math.random() * 1) + 1;
        System.out.print(randGen);
        return randGen;
    }

    private JButton moveC1But, moveC2But, rollDiceButton;
    private JLabel amountRolledLabel;

    public Game() {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Main Game");
        final JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1)) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -1729570833533906839L;

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                super.paintComponent(g2d);

                int width = getWidth() / 3;
                int height = getHeight() / 11;

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight());
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height);
                }

                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);

                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
            }
        };

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel rightSidePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 1));
        moveC1But = new JButton("Move Counter 1");
        moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                diceRoll();
                moveC1Up();
                firstPanel.repaint();
                playerTurn = false;
                playerTurn2 = true;

            }
        });
        moveC2But = new JButton("Move Counter 2");
        moveC2But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                diceRoll();
                moveC3Up();
                firstPanel.repaint();
                playerTurn = false;
                playerTurn2 = true;

            }
        });
        rollDiceButton = new JButton("Roll Dice");
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC1But, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC2But, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        rightSidePanel.add(rollDiceButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.add(rightSidePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        window.setSize(700, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }

}
```